# Integrating DJI SDK into Custom Video App for Osmo Mobile 2

Tags: ios, objective-c, dji-sdk

I've downloaded and ran the iOS DJI Mobile SDK and was able to connect the sample app to my Osmo Mobile 2 (OM2) device but there were no commands that really controlled the OM2 that I could see.

Now I "simply" want to integrate the SDK into my video application so that I can use the zoom slider on the OM2 device to control the zoom feature of my video application.

I'm assuming I would first need to have my app establish a connection to the OM2 and then would need to be able to recognize when the zoom slider was enabled on the OM2. Is this is possible? If so, what API would be needed to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out by searching for 'zoom' in the [iOS SDK API Reference](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-api/Components/SDKManager/DJISDKManager.html) and scanning all those entries. The DJIHandheldController class has what is needed to get information about when the zoom slider has changed.

Using the "Sample Application" to test, modify the SleepModeViewController and add in the *handheldController:didUpdateHardwareState* delegate method (from DJIHandheldControllerDelegate). For example, add the following:

```
- (void)handheldController:(DJIHandheldController *)controller didUpdateHardwareState:(DJIHandheldControllerHardwareState *)state {
    switch (state.zoomSlider) {
    case DJIHandheldZoomSliderZoomIn:
        NSLog(@"zoom in");
        break;
    case DJIHandheldZoomSliderZoomOut:
        NSLog(@"zoom out");
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

And that will get you what is needed. Hope this helps someone else.